# Tensorflow - Text Classification - Shapes (None,) and (None, 250, 100) are incompatible error

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to classify text with multiple labels. I use TextVectorization layer and CategoricalCrossEntropy function. Here is my model code:

Text Vectorizer:

```
def custom_standardization(input_data):
  print(input_data[:5])
  lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_data)
  stripped_html = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, '<br />', ' ')
  return tf.strings.regex_replace(stripped_html,
                                  '[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation),
                                  '')

max_features = 10000
sequence_length = 250

vectorize_layer = layers.TextVectorization(
    standardize=custom_standardization,
    max_tokens=max_features,
    output_mode='int',
    output_sequence_length=sequence_length)
```

Model generation:

```
MAX_TOKENS_NUM = 5000  # Maximum vocab size.
MAX_SEQUENCE_LEN = 40  # Sequence length to pad the outputs to.
EMBEDDING_DIMS = 100

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string))
model.add(vectorize_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(MAX_TOKENS_NUM + 1, EMBEDDING_DIMS))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss=losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=tf.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy())
```

FIT :

```
epochs = 10
history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y=y_train,
    epochs=epochs)
```

`x_train` is a list of texts like `['This is a text about science.', 'This is a text about art',...]`

`y_train` also is a list of texts like `['Science','Art',...]`

When I try to run fitting code it gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None,) and (None, 250, 100) are incompatible
```

What am i doing wrong? And also I'd like to learn if it's a good approach/model for classifying test with multiple labels?

**EDIT**:

I edited my code according to Frightera's answer. Here is my model:

```
MAX_TOKENS_NUM = 5000  # Maximum vocab size.
MAX_SEQUENCE_LEN = 40  # Sequence length to pad the outputs to.
EMBEDDING_DIMS = 100

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string))
model.add(vectorize_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(MAX_TOKENS_NUM + 1, EMBEDDING_DIMS))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(len(labels)))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss=losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy())
```

And I pass `y_train_int` instead of `y_train` by converting categories to indexes with `y_train_int = [get_label_index(label) for label in y_train]`

```
epochs = 10
history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y=y_train_int,
    epochs=epochs)
```

Now the model fits, but when I check loss function with `plt.plot(history.history['loss'])` it's an all zero line like below:

[image: Model loss function]

Is this model good for classification. Do I need those layers between input layer and final Dense Layer(Embedding etc.)? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 2:**
I have the above model now. I am using SparseCategoricalEntropy and passing to the last Dense layer length of labels which is 78 and now it fits the model.

Now when I use `model.predict(x_test)`, it gives following results:

```
array([[ 1.3232083 ,  3.4263668 ,  0.3206688 , ..., -1.9279423 ,
        -0.83103067, -5.3442082 ],
       [ 0.11507592, -2.0753977 , -0.07149621, ..., -0.27729607,
        -1.132122  , -2.4074485 ],
       [ 0.87828857, -0.5063573 ,  1.5770453 , ...,  0.72519284,
         0.50958884,  3.7006462 ],
       ...,
       [ 0.35316354, -3.1919005 , -0.25520897, ..., -1.648859  ,
        -2.2707412 , -4.321298  ],
       [ 0.89357865,  1.3001428 ,  0.17324057, ..., -0.8185719 ,
        -1.4108973 , -3.674326  ],
       [ 1.6258209 , -0.59622926,  0.7382731 , ..., -0.8473997 ,
        -0.90670204, -4.043623  ]], dtype=float32)
```

How can I convert these to labels?

Comment: You want to classify texts but model ends with an Embedding layer. Clearly this gives shape mismatch error, in this scenario you'll need dense layer as the last layer.

Comment: Okay so I changed it to dense now it gives 'UNIMPLEMENTED: Cast string to float is not supported'. May it be related to y=y_train - maybe I should convert it to integers?

Comment: Yes, it was because of string list of y input - i changed it to list of integers.

Comment: 8066 topics exist. Why would I need one-hot encoding, I'm not classifying y_train, I'm classifying x_train - y_train are the categories - x_train are text.

Comment: The last layer should have as many neurons as the number of unique labels. If the labels are integers you need to use SparseCat.Entropy. In order to use CategoricalCrossentropy they need to be one hot encoded.

Comment: @Frightera Okay than I changed it and edited my question. Now it fits. When I used model.predict it gives float results, how can i convert them to labels? And if I give to model.fit the target as string than will the result be labels directly? If so, how can I one_hot encode labels?

Comment: So it gives a number for each category identifying the likelihood. I wrote a function to convert the results to labels according to that. I took the max value of the result layer than it's the predicted category. But when I compared with the real values they are all wrong. Is this logic correct? @Frightera Thanks..

Comment: So I increased the epoch count and now it works good. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Neural networks work with numbers, you can not expect to get a string result directly. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this according to the comments as follows for text classification:

1. Use Dense layer with number of unique labels in the end of the model.
2. Convert string category labels to indexes and use SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy and SparseCategoricalAccuracy in the model.
3. When converting results to string labels, get the max valued output and get index of it in the labels list.